# Remove left padding and margin of First Level of li element of ul

Tags: html, css

I have this nested Ul li element

Lists can be nested (list inside list)

The first level of li elements Coffee, Tea and Milk taking default Padding and Margin. How to remove the first level of li elements left margin and padding.

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ul>
      <li>Black tea</li>
      <li>Green tea</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: That is the default `padding-left` applied to `ul`, from the browser stylesheet.

Comment: Yes but how to remove it?

Comment: By _overwriting_ it with a value you like more, via your own stylesheet?

Comment: Yes i have tried a lot and did not got a sloution. Thats why i posted here

Comment: We can not guess what you might have tried. In cases like this, you should _show us_ - only then can we possibly tell where you might have gone wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some parent for this first `ul` element (for example some `div`), you can use direct child selector `>`:

```
div > ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

but if you have only this structure you posted above, you can use `:not` selector:

```
ul:not(li ul) {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

you can also reset padding and margin for the first `ul` element and in the next CSS rule overwrite it for `ul` nested in `ul`:

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul ul {
  margin: revert;
  padding: revert;
}
```

`revert` will reset `margin` and `padding` to the previous value, but you can also use just some value, like `10px` instead of `revert`

Answer (score 0):

.first-ul{display: inline;}
add this class